# Node.js Object [object Object] has no method error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Express.js for my app and mongodb for database (also mongodb Nativ driver).

I created a model with two functions, for getting posts and comments:

```
// Get single Post
exports.posts = function(id,callback){

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
      } else {

        console.log('Connection established to', url);

        var collection = db.collection('posts');

        collection.find({psotId:id}).limit(1).toArray(function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            return callback(new Error("An error has occured"));
          } else {
            callback(null,result);
          }
          db.close();
        });
      }
    });

}

// Get post comments
exports.comments = function(id,callback){

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
      } else {      
        console.log('Connection established to', url);
        var collection = db.collection('comments');
        collection.find({postId:id}).toArray(function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            return callback(new Error("An error has occured"));
          } 
          else {        
            callback(null,result);
          }
          db.close();
        });
      }
    });

}
```

and I created a route to show single post:

```
var post = require('../models/post');
 //Get single post
router.get('/post/:postId',function(req,res, next){

    var id = parseInt(req.params.postId);
    post.posts(id,function(err,post){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            post.comments(post[0].id,function(err,comments){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
                else{
                    res.render('blogPost',{post:post,comments:comments})
                }
            })
        }
    })

})
```

When I run this code I get this error:

> ```
> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'comments'
> ```

When I use this two function separately its work fine:

I mean like this :

```
var post = require('../models/post');
 //Get single post
router.get('/post/:postId',function(req,res, next){

    var id = parseInt(req.params.postId);
    post.posts(id,function(err,post){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
           res.render('blogPost',{post:post})   
        }
    })

})





     //Get post comments
router.get('/post/1',function(req,res, next){

    post.comments(1,function(err,comments){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
           res.render('blogPost',{comments:comments})   
        }
    })

})
```

But when I use `post.comments` as callback for `post.posts` I get an error.

I wants know why this happening? After some research I couldn't find a solution and I an getting confused.

Comment: Well, it seems the `post` object doesn't hold a method `comments`. What might `post` be?

Comment: @MinusFour i updated questions, as you can see , i required my model as `var post = require('../models/post');`  so post.comments ref to `exports.comments {...}` in my model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your source code you have the following:

```
var post = require('../models/post');
 //Get single post
router.get('/post/:postId',function(req,res, next){

    var id = parseInt(req.params.postId);
    post.posts(id,function(err,post){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            post.comments(post[0].id,function(err,comments){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
                else{
                    res.render('blogPost',{post:post,comments:comments})
                }
            })
        }
    })

})
```

when you are calling `post.posts` you have a callback and there you have a return value which you called `post` (which it is the same variable name of `var post = require('../models/post');`

Basically change it in the callback like this:

```
var post = require('../models/post');
 //Get single post
router.get('/post/:postId',function(req,res, next){

    var id = parseInt(req.params.postId);
    post.posts(id,function(err,posts){ //HERE changed post into posts
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            post.comments(posts[0].id,function(err,comments){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
                else{
                    res.render('blogPost',{post:posts,comments:comments})
                }
            })
        }
    })

})
```

EDIT: for better understanding I would change `var post = require('../models/post');` into `var postModel = require('../models/post');` SO it is much more understandable

EDIT 2: since he posted the real version code

Basically you have the same problem, line 37 of route.js is overriding the `movie` variable.
You have to call the variable that comes back form the callback with another name, for example `movies`like you used to do in the other 2 above.

```
router.get('/m/:movieId',function(req,res, next){

    var id = parseInt(req.params.movieId);
    movie.get(id,function(err,movies){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }else{
            movie.subtitles(movies[0].imdb,function(err,subs){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
                else{
                    res.render('moviePage',{movie:movies,subtitles:subs})
                }
            })
        }
    })

})
```

Comment: still  get same error, i dont think that would be problem because when i run `post.posts` without `post.comments` in callback its work just fine.

Comment: Yes, but you override the variable. 
you are assign the variable post on what you get from the `post.posts`.
When you do `post.posts(id, function(err, post) {` inside that function, you override the `post` variable which will become an array (the result of post.post, which clearly has no method comments)

Comment: my source code  is difference , here you can see [source code](https://gist.github.com/aalireza439/caa3edb5b48ce76a367c)

Comment: Check the EDIT 2 in this answer;)

Comment: thanks , its works , just one thing if change `movie` to `movies` i get `movies is not defined` and have to create variable `var movies = require('../models/movie');` i want know there is another way to solve this ?

Comment: Where do you  change movie to movies, I gave you already the modified code. 

you make confusion with variable names, this is why i suggested to change the model variable to moviesModel `var moviesModel = require('../models/movie');` but with this you have to change it everywhere

Answer (score 0):

If you copy-pasted this from your source then its because you mispelled the method.

```
post.commencts
```

should be

```
post.comments
```